# convert null to 0

Tags: sql, null

I have the script:

```
SELECT 
    dtypcode,
    debtornum AS 'Debtor Number',
    debtorchk AS 'Check Digit',
    balancedr AS 'Debit Balance',
    balancecr AS 'Credit Balance' ,
    balancedr + balancecr AS 'Balance'
FROM 
    [pthdbo].[ldrdtyp] A
JOIN 
    [pthdbo].[ldrdbtr] B ON A.tpkldrdtyp = B.tfkldrdtyp
WHERE 
    ((balancedr + balancecr) > '0'
      OR (balancedr + balancecr) < '0')
    --debtornum = '921835'
    AND dtypcode = 'OODEB'
```

It returns the following:

```
    OODEB       921846  1   550.00  -380.00 170.00
    OODEB       922009  5   715.00  -725.00 -10.00
```

however if we look only at  debtornum  '921835' we see the below:

```
   OODEB        921835  4   200.00  NULL    NULL
```

Due to the fact that the Credit Balance of debtornum  '921835'   is NULL and not 0, the computation does not work and it is not being shown in the query result as a balance.

We do not want to update the table to reflect 0 where it may be NULL - can anyone shed light on  a solution that converts any NULL values in either the   'Debit Balance' or 'Credit Balance' fields 'on-the-fly' so that a balance will be reflected if there is either credit balance or debit balance in the table along with the NULL for the other column.

Thanks in advance,

JR

Comment: How about using ISNULL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `coalesce()` function

```
SELECT 
   dtypcode,
   debtornum    AS 'Debtor Number',
   debtorchk    AS 'Check Digit',
   coalesce(balancedr,0)    AS 'Debit Balance',
   coalesce(balancecr,0)    AS 'Credit Balance' ,
   coalesce(balancedr,0) + coalesce(balancecr,0) AS 'Balance'
   FROM [pthdbo].[ldrdtyp] A
   JOIN [pthdbo].[ldrdbtr] B
   ON A.tpkldrdtyp = B.tfkldrdtyp
   WHERE ((coalesce(balancedr,0) + coalesce(balancecr,0)) > '0'
   OR (coalesce(balancedr,0) + coalesce(balancecr,0)) < '0')
   --debtornum = '921835'
   AND dtypcode = 'OODEB'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use COALESCE to deal with the NULL's on the fly which is generic

```
COALESCE(balancedr,0)
```

In SQL Server you can use ISNULL()

```
ISNULL(balancedr,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use ISNULL Method

ISNULL(Parameter,0)

```
SELECT 
 dtypcode,
 debtornum AS 'Debtor Number',
 debtorchk AS 'Check Digit',
 ISNULL(balancedr,0) AS 'Debit Balance',
 ISNULL(balancecr,0) AS 'Credit Balance' ,
 ISNULL(balancedr + balancecr) AS 'Balance'
 FROM [pthdbo].[ldrdtyp] A
 JOIN [pthdbo].[ldrdbtr] B
 ON A.tpkldrdtyp = B.tfkldrdtyp
 WHERE ((balancedr + balancecr) > '0'
 OR (balancedr + balancecr) < '0')
 --debtornum = '921835'
 AND dtypcode = 'OODEB'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 dtypcode,
 debtornum    AS 'Debtor Number',
 debtorchk    AS 'Check Digit',
 balancedr    AS 'Debit Balance',
 balancecr    AS 'Credit Balance' ,
 balancedr + balancecr AS 'Balance'
 FROM [pthdbo].[ldrdtyp] A
 JOIN [pthdbo].[ldrdbtr] B
 ON A.tpkldrdtyp = B.tfkldrdtyp
 WHERE ((ISNULL(balancedr,0) + ISNULL(balancecr,0)) > '0'
 OR (ISNULL(balancedr,0) + ISNULL(balancecr,0)) < '0')
 --debtornum = '921835'
 AND dtypcode = 'OODEB'
```